# Caffe net.predict() , predict same probability

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, caffe

I trained pre-trained ResNet-101 following caffe model(By Kaiming He github) with 800000 data for training and 200000 data for validation. After I train this model, I got 59% accuracy for 1st and accuracy-top5 is 82% with 30 epoch as seen below picture.

[image: Training process]

But when I tried predict some images with this model(net.forward()), the results always produce same probability like below even though I tried with other images.

[image: Produces same output]

First thing I thought was image preprocessing problem in predict step like subtracting mean values or adequating batch size corresponding with training step. But all of these step was correctly set up. 
I checked all other questions having a same problem with me but couldn't find a solution. As the above picture(1) is showing, I assume the training process wasn't something wrong.

I followed "[Image Classification and Filter Visualization(00-classification.ipynb)](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb)" file provided from Caffe editing `model_def` and `model_weights` with my `model_def` and `model_weights` having a 30 epoch.

Comment: If possible, do add a link to the file: _Image Classification and Filter Visualization(00-classification.ipynb)_

Comment: The link is http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb also ResNet-101 is https://github.com/KaimingHe/deep-residual-networksbecause because of reputation I couldn't post more than 2 links. Thank u

Comment: Could you be more clear about the solution?
I'm having the same problem but I di not understand what did you do to solve the issue.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. The problem was use_global_stats setting in deploy.prototxt. In training step, use_global_stats has to be set as false because mean/var need's to be update. But when I predict using deploy.prototxt use_global_stats has to be set as true.